# How do I fill dict's values in one list with dict's values from another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I have 2 lists with dicts in each and I need to fill values in second list with values from the first one based on 'id' key. Right now I am using code below, but it feels too complicated (too many iterations). Is there a more pythonic way?

```
a = [{'id':1, 'tag':'11'},{'id':2, 'tag':'12'},{'id':3, 'tag':'13'},{'id':4, 'tag':'14'}]
b = [{'id':1, 'tag':None},{'id':2, 'tag':None},{'id':3, 'tag':None},{'id':4, 'tag':None}, {'id':5, 'tag':None}]

for item1 in a:
    for item2 in b:
        if item1['id'] == item2['id']:
            item2['tag'] = item1['tag']
```

Comment: If the keys are the same, why not just do `b = a` ?

Comment: When you have a list of dictionaries, that's sometimes indicative of a bad choice in data structures. Why do you need a list of dicts? Why can't you make your lists a single dict, and make "id" the key and "tag" the value.

Comment: @Falmarri To take it a step further, if the 'id' field is always sequential, just use a list of the 'tag' values.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do something like

```
a = [{'id':1, 'tag':'11'},{'id':2, 'tag':'12'},{'id':3, 'tag':'13'},{'id':4, 'tag':'14'}]
b = [{'id':1, 'tag':None},{'id':2, 'tag':None},{'id':3, 'tag':None},{'id':4, 'tag':None}, {'id':5, 'tag':None}]


b[0:len(a)] = a
```

Comment: Style tip:  You can omit the `0` in `b[0:len(a)]` since Python sets the start position to `0` by default.

Comment: This matches by position, not by id. Are the ids really redundant? Also you're replacing the dicts in `b` with references to the dicts in `a`; if you modify `a`'s dicts later, `b` will change as well!

Comment: True True,  but I was just suggesting a quick pythonic way.  It could run into problems. But it works for this example.  I'm not sure how specific of an example he is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems incorrect; you have two lists of dicts, and you copy the value of `tag` only when two dictionaries match in id *and* in list position. If the lists are exactly matched you don't need to check the ids, and if you need to check the ids, you shouldn't care where the dictionary appears. So let's assume the ID is important; the standard way to match by ID is to index them all in another dictionary. So I'd do it like this:

```
index = [ (item1["id"], item1) for item1 in a ]
for item2 in b:
    if item2['id'] in index:
        item2['tag'] = index[ item2['id'] ]['tag']
```

That's clear, but you can avoid the double lookup by immediately fetching and saving the value,
if possible:

```
index = [ (item1["id"], item1) for item1 in a ]
for item2 in b:
    try:
        id2 = item2["id"]
        newval = index[id2]["tag"]
        item2["tag"] = newval
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building a new dictionary, that pairs up ID values with tag values.  Then you can make one pass over `a` and update the values you want updated.  Here's the clearest code I can write:

```
bvals = {d['id']:d['tag'] for d in b}

for d in a:
    id_val = d['id']
    if id_val in bvals:
        d['tag'] = bvals[id_val]
```

It's a little bit more terse, but you can do it with less code this way:

```
for d in a:
    d['tag'] = bvals.get(d['id'], d['tag'])
```

This relies on the `.get()` method on dictionaries, which returns the value indexed by a key if there is one, and returns a default value if the key is not present in the dictionary.  This code uses the value already stored in the dict under the key `tag` as the default.